# can I display total count of all the stacked series - stacked grouped highchart- Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I want to add total count on top of every column series maintaining the stacklabels and all the datalabels present inside the bar chart
my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rq8m7e0v/

code:

```
chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', "getete"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
     
       
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          y:90,
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
              return this.stack;
            }
          
        }
    },
 
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
 series: [{
          name: 'John',
          data: [53, 33, 43,63,7,83],
          stack: 'male'
        }, {
          name: 'Joe',
          data: [33, 43,43,63,73,8],
          stack: 'female'
        }, {
          name: 'Jane',
          data: [42, 54,43,62,74,84],
          stack: 'male',
        
        }, {
          name: 'Janet',
          data: [34, 40, 42,36,74,83],
          stack: 'female',
        }]
```

any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display total count of all the bar values at the top- Highcharts colum- react highhcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150912/how-to-display-total-count-of-all-the-bar-values-at-the-top-highcharts-colum-r)

Comment: no it didt work, I tried that before raising this one

Comment: You need to define the dataLabels as an array of object config to have more than one dataLabels group in your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zbck6L2j/